# How does one construct a query that only returns this months rows, based on Timestamp?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm curious what the right way is to construct a query where the rows are pulled based on a timestamp that represents a specific month.  Given that different months have different numbers of days, is there a way to generate a query that always gives you the rows where the timestamp contains the current month so that the results would only include the current month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 
MONTH(timesp) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
YEAR(timesp) = YEAR(NOW());
```

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampField))==6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MONTH`:

```
select *
from foo
where month_column = MONTH(getdate())
and year_column = YEAR(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql.

```
select *
from yourtable
where yourdatefield>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table where MONTH(date_row) = $month;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on your date field, then this is efficient (T-SQL syntax, the idea applieas to any RDBMS though)

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  tableName 
WHERE 
  dateTimeField
    BETWEEN
      -- build the string 'YYYY-MM-01', cast back as a datetime
      CAST(
        CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS varchar) + '-01'
        AS datetime
      )
    AND
      -- add one month, subtract one day
      DATEADD(mm, 1,
        -- build the string 'YYYY-MM-01', cast back as a datetime
        CAST(
          CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS varchar) + '-01'
          AS datetime
        )
      ) - 1
```

Of course any other method to get two datetime values in the right range would work.

SQL Server has `LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 120), 8) + '01'` to convert a datetime to string, other Db servers have their own functions to do the same. Maybe you can calculate the two values in the calling application more easily - how you get them, is not the point.

The point is that `BETWEEN` can use an index, whereas the other solutions that work with `WHERE MONTH(dateTimeField) = 6` will trigger a table scan, which is about the slowest operation you can do on a table.